# Blacklist Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Is there a way e.g. a Maven plug in that can take a list of unwanted/black listed dependencies (direct and transitive) and fails the build if it detects one of listed dependencies?

In my project we strictly want to get rid of Apache Commons Logging and replace it with the SLF4J JCL Bridge. I am aware that we have to exclude the unwanted deps ourselfs but I would like to have the build failed if someone adds a dependency that brings in blacklisted dependency.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can ban some dependencies using the [`maven-enforcer-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html).

Here is their example with updates for your exclusion of Apache Commons Logging.

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-banned-dependencies</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <bannedDependencies>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </bannedDependencies>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

The output when running `mvn install` will be:

```
[WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BannedDependencies failed with message:
Found Banned Dependency: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1
Use 'mvn dependency:tree' to locate the source of the banned dependencies.
```

It all ends with a `BUILD FAILURE`.

Comment: I've facing that error. In my case, I want to fix it instead of failing the build: `Found Banned Dependency: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2` . My project directly doesn't use it. It uses some X which need this banned library. How do I use `X` now?

Comment: @Nawaz You can exclude transitive dependencies by using `<exclusions>` when you declare your dependencies.

Comment: I solved this using `<dependencyManagement>`. That worked for me. I wish Java ecosystem used less XML which is quite verbose and used something more concise, YAML or so.

Comment: @Nawaz I have exact same problem as yours. I also don't want to fail my build. How did you solve this using dependencyManagement?

Comment: @Sankalp: You can explicitly mention the list of transitive dependencies under `<dependencyManagement>` and while doing so you can also use `<exclusions>` to exclude problematic version of the deps. I guess Maven will try to find the next best match version (for the deps) for you. Here is how my `pom.xml` looks like:  https://gist.github.com/snawaz/9fdf4824b41a53e912090d5b70bf7e24 .. Hope that helps. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/) supports this with its [bannedDependencies](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) rule.

Comment: Another favourite of mine is the [banDuplicateClasses](http://mojo.codehaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banDuplicateClasses.html) rule in the codehaus extra enforcer rules library. This would detect the duplicate classes introduced by  dependencies on both `commons-logging` and `jcl-over-slf4j`.