# How to simplify same exclusion on multiple dependencies in maven pom

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have several dependencies in my pom that pull in an unwanted jar so the same exclusion is set on them:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>some.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-artifact-1</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>annoying.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>unwanted-artifact</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>some.other.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-artifact-2</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>annoying.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>unwanted-artifact</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>another.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>some-artifact-3</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>annoying.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>unwanted-artifact</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  .
  .
  .
<dependencies>
```

The problem is my poms have dozens of dependencies so there are potentially more that pull in the unwanted jar. I'm not sure how to discern the dependencies that don't pull in that unwanted dependency from those who do.

My workflow right now is:

1. Look through my pom and add the exclusion on the dependencies that *look* like they might need it (judging from the artifact and group IDs).
2. Confirm the jar is no longer in my project's Maven Dependencies list in Eclipse
3. Add more exclusions until the jar is gone if it isn't already.
4. **Painfully** go through each dependency I gave an exclusion to and switch the exclusion off to confirm whether the exclusion is actually needed.

**My question is: is there a better way? Is there a way to set a general exclusion in my pom so I don't have to repeat the same exclusion over and over again? Or is there a better workflow to exclude this unwanted jar?**

I'm using Maven 3.0.4

Comment: Why not using the Maven enforcer plugin ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794049/blacklist-maven-dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there is no way to avoid this. 'Global' dependency exclusion has been discussed but never implemented.